# Abstract Syntax Tree generator for javascript, but available in groovy?

Tags: javascript, groovy, abstract-syntax-tree

I was using the [esprima](http://esprima.org/doc/index.html) AST generator for javascript and using node.js.  It works great!

Now I need to process the resultant json and would really like to use groovy - I have used groovy for this very successfully in the past.  I could use two passes (first use node to create the json files and then use a groovy script to process them).  However, given the large number of files I will be processing it is preferable to me to use groovy entirely.

Does anyone know if a AST generator for javascript is available in either Java or groovy?  Google searches were fruitless for me - way too many hits!

[*Afterthought*: If node.js is callable from groovy, then I would need a ***really*** good set of directions on how that might be made to work!]